# Harmonic functions in infinite domain in Euclidean space

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory, physics, harmonic-functions

**EDIT**: Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary.  Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \bar\Omega$ and vanishes on $\partial \Omega$. Let us also assume that $f$ vanishes at infinity.

**What assumptions on the decay rate at infinity imply that $f\equiv 0$?**

The case $n=3$ is of special interest to me.

**ADD:** The motivation of my question comes from the very classical problem from electrostatics ($n=3$) which is probably solved. Assume the domain $\Omega$ is filled with a conductor and electrified with a charge. All the charged is necessarily accumulated on the surface of the domain. The potential of the created electric field in the space is a harmonic function outside if the domain and is constant on the boundary. It decays at infinity like $1/r^2$. **Is such potential unique? Equivalently, is distribution of charge on the surface is unique?**

Probably this is a very well studied question, but I am not a specialist.

Comment: You'd at least have to say something about the boundary conditions on the surface of the ball ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt: well, there is a bounded smooth domain containing the ball, such that on its boundary the function vanishes.

Comment: Without boundary conditions there is no rate that suffice. In $n = 3$ for example $\partial_1^m \frac1r$ is harmonic and decays like $r^{-1-m}$.

Comment: @WillieWong: You are right, thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: Any harmonic function which vanishes on $\partial\Omega$ AND at $\infty$ is evidently zero. This follows from the Maximum Principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "vanish at infinity" means that

> for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a sufficiently large ball $B_\epsilon$ such that $\big|f|_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_\epsilon}\big| < \epsilon$

then you can just apply the maximum principle to $B_\epsilon \setminus \Omega$  and conclude that $f$ is bounded by $\epsilon$ on that set.

Take $\epsilon \to 0$ you get that $f$ must vanish identically.

No decay rate needed.