# Harmonic function in infinite domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$, constant on the boundary and decaying as $1/r^2$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis, physics, harmonic-functions

**EDIT**: Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a bounded domain with smooth connected boundary.  Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3\backslash \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash \bar\Omega$ and constant on $\partial \Omega$.

Let us assume that $f$ decays at infinity as $O(1/r^2)$.

**Is it true that $f\equiv 0$?**

This question is a strengthened version of this one [Harmonic functions in infinite domain in Euclidean space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403696/harmonic-functions-in-infinite-domain-in-euclidean-space#403696) which contained an unnecessary assumption.

The motivation to ask this question comes from a classical question in electrostatics. Assume that the domain $\Omega$ is filled in with a conductor which is electrically neutral. Can the charge of the conductor redistribute in a non-trivial way so that the conductor will be in equilibrium?

Comment: $g(x)=|x|^{2-n} f(x/|x|^2)$ in $R^n$.

Comment: And that $g(x)=O(|x|^2)$ for $x \approx 0$ indicates that there is no singularity at $x=0$, hence $g$ is harmonic with constant boundary values.

Comment: @LeechLattice: If $\Omega$ is not a Euclidean ball then $g$ is not constant on the boundary. But in the Euclidean ball this answers the question.

Comment: @makt  Even if $\Omega$ is not an Euclidean ball, if $f$ is nonzero at its boundary, $g$ will be bounded away from zero at its boundary (though not constant); in this case it's impossible to have $g(0)=0$ as $g$ is harmonic.

Comment: @LeechLattice: Looks like the final answer.

Comment: Just a remark (this also applies to the previous question you refer to): Your physical motivation does not match your mathematical question. The potential you describe (constant on the boundary, decaying as $1/r^3 $) does not come from a conductor.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt : You are right: it should be $1/r^2$.  Corrected.

Comment: Hmm, no, it can't be $1/r^2 $ either, that's the behavior of a dipole. For a (connected) conductor, your only options are: It is charged, then the leading behavior at infinity is $\sim 1/r$; or it is neutral, then the potential $f\equiv 0$. If you want a dipole, you need to have at least two conductors disconnected from one another.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I may finally be understanding your question: Perhaps the uniqueness theorem you seek is this one: "The electric field of a collection of conductors is uniquely determined if the total charge on each conductor is given." This is shown, e.g., in Griffiths' "Introduction to Electrodynamics" (section 3.1.6 in the 3rd edition). Does that help?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt : I am trying to prove the following.  Assume that in a cavity of a conductor there are charges with total charge 0. Then outside of the conductor there is no electric field.

Comment: Ah, I see. I would argue like this (and you've said most of this already): All that matters for the electric field outside is the constant $f_0 =f|_{\partial \Omega }$, and the question boils down to what we can say about $f_0 $. Let's show that $f_0 \neq 0$ is inconsistent with your specifications. $f_0 \neq 0$ would be equally produced by a *charged* solid (without the cavity) conductor - an uncharged one would (uniquely) produce $f_0 =0$. But a charged solid conductor would produce asymptotic behavior $f\sim 1/r$ (continued ...)

Comment: ... so this is inconsistent with your specification that $f$ falls off faster than that. It is likewise inconsistent with your specification that the original conductor with cavity and charges is overall neutral. So we're left with $f_0 =0$, and therefore $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is of one sign on $\partial\Omega$, then $f$ is of the same sign everywhere by the maximum principle. Now let $u(r)$ be the average of $f$ on any sphere centered at the origin which is large enough not to intersect with $\Omega$. Then we have $u''(r)+(2/r)u'(r)=0$, which is inconsistent with the decay you require unless $u=0$.